# Kotlin RecyclerView with static rows is only vertical

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a RecyclerView with static rows. You can see my code below, all functions are called in the onViewCreated(...) function of a fragment.

```
private fun setupRecyclerViews() {
    adapterDoSports = InterestAdapter(viewModel, "doSports")
    setupRecyclerView(adapterDoSports, binding.recyclerViewDoSports)
}

private fun setupRecyclerView(
    adapterInterest: InterestAdapter,
    recyclerViewInterest: RecyclerView
) {
    recyclerViewInterest.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
    recyclerViewInterest.apply {
        adapter = adapterInterest
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    }
}

private fun setUpObservers() {
    viewModel.myUser.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                response.data?.let { userResponse ->
                    adapterDoSports.differ.submitList(
                        userResponse.interests.doSports.keys.toMutableList())
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                response.message?.let {
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred: $it")
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                //TODO: some loading animation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the recyclerview is still only vertical (I posted only the code for one RecyclerView).

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Create a new adapter instances for each recyclerview or if you're creating new instance check the submitting response adapterDoSports.differ.submitList(
                        userResponse.interests.doSports.keys.toMutableList())
                }

Comment: What's the problem exactly? If you're expecting a grid, you're setting `layoutManager` twice and replacing your `GridLayoutManager` with a vertical `LinearLayoutManager`

Comment: I missed that. I first had a LinearLayout and wanted to change it to a GridLayout. Careless mistake.